# Xcode: How to push to a scene with a programmatically created button

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, xcode5, pushviewcontroller

So I have a programmatically created array of "buttons" which are actually UIImageViews. All of the buttons can create an action, or give an Alert. When this button is pushed I want it to go to a scene in my storyboard. Here is the code that I've tried out that I thought would have worked:

```
    if (b3.alpha>0.75 && CGRectContainsPoint(b3.frame, location))
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"News" sender:self];
    }
```

I have a segue from the menu view controller to my news view controller with my Segue Identifier as News. My problem is that if I were push to the NewsViewController's class the news display doesn't register for some reason. It seemed that if i set the news scene to the initial view controller it works perfectly, and I've put a button on the scene temporarily and pushed from button to scene and that worked perfectly as well.

I've looked around for another solution but no matter what I try it either will not go to the scene in the storyboard or i'll keep getting libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is your Main View Controller wrapped in a Navigation Controller?

Comment: You should post the actual error message.

Comment: My Main View Controller is wrapped in a navigation controller

Comment: I think I may have also put the wrong error message:

Comment: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/MyName/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/8E860D29-D6A0-4C41-8655-0B38DA144580/MyApp.app> (loaded)' with name 'NewsViewController' and directory 'MainStoryboard.storyboardc''

Comment: i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415252/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-could-not-load-nib-in-bundle

Comment: The weird thing is, if I comment out the code and then set the News Controller as the initial view controller it works perfectly. But if I try to push to the scene programmatically through the Main view controller with a segue it give me that error.

Comment: Why are you using UIViews instead of buttons? It's probably better to use a custom UIButton instead.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984500/how-to-make-custom-buttons-in-ios